# Linux C, File validation not working

Tags: c, linux, validation

I wanted to make a simple file validation function in C, to verify a file exists before reading it. For some reason, my validation code keeps returning false for a valid file. The file is in the same location as the compiled program. I tried using the full path, and only the file path. Why is my function failing to find the file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
// #include <linux/string.h>
const char* CONFIG_FILE =  "/home/matt/atc_config"; //"/config.ini";

bool path_status (char *s_path);

//bool Validate_File(const char* path);
//bool Read_Config_File(const char* path, char* contents);
//bool Parse_Config_Data(const char* data, MeterParams* mp);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Get path to config file. This assumes our config file
    // is kept in the same folder as this execuable file.

    char file[256];
    strcpy (file, argv[0]);
    strcat (file, CONFIG_FILE);

    puts ( file );

// Validate config file is present and we
// can access it.
if ( path_status ( CONFIG_FILE )) // ( file ))
{
    puts ("file ok.");
    // Read the file's contents.

}
else
{
    puts ("file not ok.");
}

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

bool path_status (char *s_path)
{
   /* The following mask values are defined for the file type of the
   st_mode field:
   * 
       S_IFMT     0170000   bit mask for the file type bit field

       S_IFSOCK   0140000   socket
       S_IFLNK    0120000   symbolic link
       S_IFREG    0100000   regular file
       S_IFBLK    0060000   block device
       S_IFDIR    0040000   directory
       S_IFCHR    0020000   character device
       S_IFIFO    0010000   FIFO
* ref: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html
*/ 

// 'stat'returns information about file, folder, link or socket.
// It fills a structure, also named 'stat'.
// On success, zero is returned. On error, -1 is returned, and
// errno is set appropriately.

struct stat st;
bool ret = false;    
if (stat(s_path , &st) == 0) // // Zero indicates path status successfully obtained.
{
    ret = (st.st_mode & S_IFMT == S_IFREG); 
}    
    return ret;
}
```

Thanks, 
Matt

Comment: Relational and equality operators like `==` bind more tightly than bitwise operators like `&`.  Your test, therefore, is equivalent to `ret = (st.st_mode & (S_IFMT == S_IFREG));`, and since `S_IFMT` is almost certainly not equal to `S_IFREG`, you are anding `0` with `st.st_mode` which is always 0 or false.

Comment: Hey, I got it working. I added a set of parenthesis, and this line returns true now.    ret = ((st.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG);

Comment: Note that you don't do this in real programs, **ever**. Instead, you just open the file. If `fopen()` returns NULL, you examine `errno` to find why the file could not be opened. I like to use `fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", filename, strerror(errno));` to report the reason. [`strerror()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html), [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), and [`fopen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) returning the error this way is all perfectly standard C since C89.

Comment: Thanks animal, but what's wrong with using stat to validate a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a precedence error here:

```
ret = (st.st_mode & S_IFMT == S_IFREG);
```

This parses as

```
ret = (st.st_mode & (S_IFMT == S_IFREG));
```

because `==` binds tighter than `&` (for silly reasons). `S_IFMT == S_IFREG` is `0`, `anything & 0` is `0`, so `ret` is always `0`.

---

Fix:

```
ret = (st.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG;
```

Comment: Yup, I just noticed this too, did not know why. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
ret = (st.st_mode & S_IFMT == S_IFREG);
```

The `==` operator has higher precedence than the `&` operator.  So what is actually happening is this:

```
ret = (st.st_mode & (S_IFMT == S_IFREG));
```

Add parenthesis in the proper place and it will work as expected:

```
ret = ((st.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG);
```

Also, you forget to `#include <string.h>`, which contains the declaration for `strcpy` and `strcat`.

Comment: Thanks. I included stdio and stdlib, and my compiler is happy without the string include.

Comment: @MattFomich Then you probably don't have warnings turned up high enough.  When using gcc, you should use `-Wall -Wextra` to warn on other things that might cause an error.